# Covert html to pdf, calculate the vertical space to the end of the last page faster

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a custom puppeteer script which converts dynamic generated HTML to an A4 PDF.
This script converts HTML to a near perfect A4 PDF file, the only issue I have is speed. Document conversion is anywhere between 1-10 minutes.

I have tracked the slowness to the part where we calculate how much vertical space needs to be added to the last page
in order to have a full page. If we don't do this the background we have will be clipped.

Next up the relevant code, which is called as followed;

```
node convert.js "{\"url\":\"file://$(pwd)/generated.html\",\"options\":{\"path\":\"$(pwd)/generated.pdf\"}}"
```

```
async function addPadding(page) {
    await page.emulateMedia('print');

    await page.evaluate(
        _ => {
            let container = document.querySelector('#padding-container');

            if (container)
                container.style.height = '1145px'
        }
    );

    return Promise.resolve()
}

function getPageAmount(buffer) {
    let index = buffer.indexOf('/Count ');
    let string = buffer.slice(index + '/Count '.length, index + '/Count '.length + 32).toString();
    return ~~string.trim().split(/\n|\/|\[|\>/)[0]
}
```

`convert.js`

```
(async _ => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: [
            isDocker ? '--no-sandbox' : ''
        ],
        defaultViewport: {
            width: 724,
            height: 1145 * 32
        }
    });
    const page  = await browser.newPage();

    await page.emulateMedia('print');
    await page.goto(request.url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    await page.setViewport({ width: 724, height: 1145 });

    let buffer = await render(page);
    let originalPages = getPageAmount(buffer);
    let maxPasses = 3;
    let passes = 0;

    await addPadding(page);

    buffer = await render(page);

    while(getPageAmount(buffer) !== originalPages && passes < maxPasses) {
        await page.evaluate(
            _ => {
                let paddingContainer = document.querySelector('#padding-container');
                let value = ~~paddingContainer.style.height.replace('px', '');
                paddingContainer.style.height = `${value / 2}px`
            }
        );

        buffer = await render(page);

        if (getPageAmount(buffer) === originalPages) {
            while (getPageAmount(buffer) === originalPages) {
                await page.evaluate(
                    _ => {
                        let paddingContainer = document.querySelector('#padding-container');
                        let value = ~~paddingContainer.style.height.replace('px', '');
                        paddingContainer.style.height = `${value * 1.5}px`
                    }
                );

                buffer = await render(page)
            }
        }

        passes++
    }

    while(getPageAmount(buffer) !== originalPages) {
        await page.evaluate(
            _ => {
                let paddingContainer = document.querySelector('#padding-container');
                let value = ~~paddingContainer.style.height.replace('px', '');
                paddingContainer.style.height = `${value - 1}px`
            }
        );

        buffer = await render(page)
    }

    if (request.options.path)
        fs.writeFileSync(request.options.path, buffer);

    browser.close()
})();
```

I really would appreciate any feedback/help on this.

Comment: You bounce between "I" & "we" a bit in that description. Is this your code, or a collaborative effort? There are also no comments describing what happens.

Comment: @t145 it's a collaborative effort. Initial work was done by a freelancer, I'm now tasked with finding out if it can be optimized

Comment: If you're willing to work in Python somehow, there's this library for just that: https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/ As for pure JS, a simple search yields some promising results: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+html+to+pdf&t=ffab&ia=web For each ex there's not an excess usage of while loops, so that's likely your performance sink.

Comment: @T145 I have no problem with Python, will try that out. However, I don't expect a better outcome than my current approach. Since I'm now controlling a headless chrome instance to create the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ways to optimize:

***Nested loops***

You got nested `while` loops in `convert.js` script and that requires a particular attention.
The outer `while` loop contains the construction:

```
...
if (getPageAmount(buffer) === originalPages) {
    while (getPageAmount(buffer) === originalPages) {
...
```

where `if` conditional redundantly checks the condition `getPageAmount(buffer) === originalPages` whereas the underling `while` loop would check the same condition by itself. Therefore, remove the redundant `if` "wrapper".

---

**`getPageAmount`** ***function***

Deserves a separate attention (frequently invoked function).

- `'/Count '`. Many-times hardcoded search string `'/Count '` begs for extracting into a variable

  ```
  let searchStr = '/Count ';
  ```
- `index + '/Count '.length`. Duplicated expression points to a starting offset for input buffer slicing. 
  Worth to be a variable:

  ```
  let pos = buffer.indexOf(searchStr);
  let startOffset = pos + searchStr.length;
  let str = buffer.slice(startOffset, startOffset + 32).toString();
  ```
- *splitting a string by pattern and get the 1st chunk* (`~~string.trim().split(/\n|\/|\[|\>/)[0]`). 
  What it does is splitting the input string by regex pattern `/\n|\/|\[|\>/` into array of substrings. 
  Though it creates a new array of strings/chunks in memory - whereas we only need the ***1st leftmost*** chunk `.[0]`.
  Instead, a much more efficient way is to just find the position of the 1st occurrence of the pattern and slice the input string to that point.
  That's achievable with [`String.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) + `String.slice` combination and will go ***smashingly*** faster compared to the initial approach.
  Eventually the optimized function would look as:

  ```
  function getPageAmount(buffer) {
      let searchStr = '/Count ',
          pos = buffer.indexOf(searchStr),
          startOffset = pos + searchStr.length;
      let str = buffer.slice(startOffset, startOffset + 32).toString();
      return ~~str.trim().slice(0, str.search(/[\n\/\[\>]/))
  }
  ```

***DOM*** tree scanning

The "hero" of this section is `document.querySelector('#padding-container')` which appears in many places within `while` loops and queries the current `document` for a specific tag/element.
Such DOM queries become an expensive operations if used frequently, moreover - in massive traversals. Depending on markup complexity and "amount" of traversal such repetative queries may make the processing +50% slower.
The solution here is to extract the reference to an element into a top-level variable and reference it in all needed places.

```
# top-level variables
...
let passes = 0;
let paddingContainer = document.querySelector('#padding-container');
```

***Extracting*** "padding container" height

Expression `~~paddingContainer.style.height.replace('px', '')` is duplicated in many places and is candidate for *Extract function* technique.
Could be even defined as unified function for getting `height` for the element passed as parameter:

```
function getElHeight(el):
    return ~~el.style.height.replace('px', '')

...

    ...
    _ => {
        let padding_height = getElHeight(paddingContainer);
        paddingContainer.style.height = `${padding_height * 1.5}px`
    }
```